# Do we add a full stop after an ellipsis at the end of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Do we add a full stop after an ellipsis at the end of a sentence?

eg ‘There is a problem...’.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do add a full stop after the ellipsis, but it should be inside the quotation or speech marks, not outside.

> 'There is a problem....'

Grammar Monster has an article on this here:
[http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/quotation_(speech)_marks_ellipsis_three_dots.htm](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/quotation_%28speech%29_marks_ellipsis_three_dots.htm)

Comment: Grammar Monster used this example: *"A hat should be taken off when you greet a lady and left off […] nothing looks more stupid than a hat."* If we had a fragmented quote that trailed off, would we do this? *A hat should be taken off [...].* -or- *A hat should be taken off [...]* ln other words, do I place a period outside the bracket?

Comment: If you're using the brackets, use it outside the bracket. The bracket is around the ellipsis, and the period is separate. Think of the sentence without the ellipsis, and what you would normally do if it wasn't there.